# Extracting Menthol using chemistry?

Tags: extracts

I know this might be an answered question, but [how can i extract menthol powder from fresh mint peppermint](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/85308/how-can-i-extract-menthol-powder-from-fresh-mint-peppermint) doesnt really answer my question. I am wondering if i were to get a chemistry set, could i boil the menthol right out of the leaves in the form of vapor, and then condensate it for further use? This might be a question for the chemistry SE, but it kind of fits here as well.

Comment: Do you mean 'it doesn't answer your question' or do you mean, 'it looks a bit difficult'? If you could just boil some leaves & collect the steam, what makes you think that wouldn't have been the first answer?

Comment: My answer on the older question addresses exactly that: how to extract menthol from the leaves using chemistry. Maybe you read only Megha's answer there? I fail to see how this is not a duplicate. Especially since I also describe there exactly the path you are suggesting here (extraction that starts with a distillation step).